# How to insert data to this Dictionary - Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary

I need to insert data to this type of dictionary

```
var dict : Dictionary = [Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]]()
```

For inserting data I am using this construction,

```
 dict[dictionaryKey] = ([TimelinePoint(), performance.timelineColor, "12:30", performance.name, "asdf", "nil", "nil"] as? [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)])
```

where `dictionaryKey = 1 (integer)`
 This doesn't work, I didn't get any error, but dictionary is empty.

However, this works without any problem

```
let data:[Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)]] = [0:[(TimelinePoint(), UIColor.green, "12:30", "Lorem \n ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "asdf", "asdf", "Sun")]
```

Could someone help me, where is the problem?

Comment: Hello. I have two suggestions. 1) Using an int as key for a dictionary feels like you should probably use an array instead. 2) You should definitely use a struct instead of a tuple to store these values.

Comment: As for your current issue: your dictionary values are arrays of tuples, not tuples of arrays. You're casting the wrong type, it's mixed up. // But really, you should use a struct here, not a tuple, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 dict[dictionaryKey] = ([(TimelinePoint(), performance.timelineColor, "12:30", performance.name, "asdf", "nil", "nil")] as? [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, String?, String?)])
```

I think you are missing small braces "()" to surround your values in the first case. You are doing this in the second case because of which it works.

As a result, your data type in the first case is not correct.

This may solve your problem temporarily. However, you will land in trouble in future because of using tuple for such complicated data type. So follow Swift recommendation and use `Struct` instead of `Tuples` for large data types.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type doesn't match your declaration. Your declaration for the Dictionary defines each value as an array of tuples but your failed code is trying to use a tuple containing an array as your value. That's wrong.

You use a conditional cast (`as?`) in that line, and the cast fails, so your code assigns nil to the dictionary entry. Without the conditional cast you'd get a compile error. With the conditional cast you're code is compiling, but mapping to nil.

Your second assignment correctly creates a value that is an array of tuples, so it works.

Change your first assignment like this:

```
dict[dictionaryKey] = [(TimelinePoint(), performance.timelineColor, "12:30", performance.name, "asdf", nil, nil)]
```

As an aside, the string "nil" is not the same thing as nil. If you want to represent a missing value, use `nil` without quotes.

Also, as others have said, using tuples for a complex data model like this is a bad idea. Create an array of structs instead.